# How can I assign the HTML5 canvas object to a variable using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Why does in the below code, only the explicit Javascript version work, but not the Jquery version (commented out)?

```
 <html>
     <head>
         <title>Canvas Tutorial</title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <canvas id="can" width="150" height="150">Fallback</canvas>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             //var can = $("#can").get();
             var can = document.getElementById("can");
             var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
         </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

I keep receiving the notification that

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'can.getContext('2d')')
```

Answer (score 2):

Because [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) without passing any parameter returns an array-like structure. You should use:

```
var can = $("#can").get(0);
```

Or the shorthand:

```
var can = $("#can")[0];
```

To get the DOM element reference.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/cM2Fj/1/)

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

> Without a parameter, .get() returns all of the elements. [...]
>
> All of the matched DOM nodes are returned by this call, contained in a
>   standard array.

[**Testing**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/cM2Fj/2/):

```
>>> var can = $("#can").get(); console.log(can instanceof Array);
true
>>> var can = $("#can").get(0); console.log(can instanceof Array);
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [jQuery ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to select the canvas element with the `can` ID. That will give you a jQuery object. Every jQuery object masquerades as an Array so you can use standard array dereferencing to get the underlying DOM element. (See: http://api.jquery.com/get/ )

```
var can = $("#can")[0];
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
```

[Try it out!](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/8Q3vG/)